# Order of return values from functions

Tags: c++, function, return

Here is my code in C++:

```
 MyClass foo1() {
     return MyClass();
 }

 int MyClass::foo2() {
     return 54;
 }
```

And the question is, what is the value of:

```
foo1().foo2();
```

Is the value 54 or is it the MyClass object?

Comment: You could just try it...

Comment: I could, but I want some answer which will explain it why it is that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo1().foo2();` means that `foo1()` returns an object or reference to an object that allows you to call `foo2()` on it.

Similar would be to store the return value of `foo1()` in a variable:

```
MyClass obj = foo1();
int ret = obj.foo2();
```

Example (lazy-loaded singleton):

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static MyClass& getInstance(){ static MyClass m; return m; }
    int getNumber(){ return 54; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << MyClass::getInstance().getNumber();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the dot `.` operator is evaluated left-to-right (i.e. first `foo1()` is called to determine the target of the invocation, and then its `foo2()` member is invoked), the answer is 54.

Comment: That's what I wanted. Is there anyway for the value to be MyClass object?

Comment: just calling foo1() will return a MyClass.

Comment: @user1873947 Not unless `foo2()` is changed to return the `MyClass` object back to you, e.g. `MyObject foo2() { return *this; }`